# Understanding Class Mocking

Tags: spring, mocking

for controller test I have mocks like

```
bookService = createMock(BookService.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(homeController, "bookService", bookService);
here I mocked the services.
```

for unit test of service class I have mocked Repository classes

```
bookRepository = createMock(BookRepository.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookService, "bookRepository", bookRepository);
```

here I mocked BookRepository and injected to bookservices , so when we test this service class there will be no calls to database

I want to know if my understanding is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The mocking framework creates its own implementation of the interface that has nothing in common with your implementation that accesses a database - except that the classes share the same interface of course.